# Laravel ENV not reload

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-environment

I use **Laravel 6.2** with *valet* and *PHP 7.3.12*

The problem is I want to change `DB_DATABASE=laravel` to `DB_DATABASE=something_else` in `.env` file
but it doesn't reload the new .env value at all

I have already tried this command:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

but it still doesn't change at all.

I even try to add a new key to `.env` file and query it in *Tinker* and the new key doesn't add as well.

Comment: so you execute `env('DB_DATABASE')` and you aren't getting the new value?

Comment: @lagbox yes it still get ```env('DB_DATABASE')=laravel```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After completion of `.env` edit, You can clear the configuration cache with the following artisan command: `php artisan config:cache`

Use `php artisan key:generate` it will generate the new key to your `.env` file

---

**NOTE: If there is still error** then you do not need your restart computer just try this:

If you are using the PHP's default web server (eg. `php artisan serve`) you need to **restart** your server

*OR*

If you have used **XAMPP** then restart your **Apache** server

Answer (score 1):

I just restart my computer at first it doesn't work then I did
`php artisan config:cache` and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

whenever you want to change content `.env` file

run `php artisan cache:clear` command to get newly added values

Answer (score 0):

Restarting you computer has nothing to do with it.

If you are working on a local environment then please stop your development server by pressing `ctrl+c` and then restart the application by running `php artisan serve`.

Comment: I use valet and I did run ```valet restart``` but it didn't help.